# Cartan's Signature of curve after Euclidean and Equi-affine transform

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, computer-science, curves

Let's start with definitions:

For given curve $C(x(t),y(t))$ in $R^2$ when $t\in[a,b]$.

Cartan's signature that defined in the following way:
$\{\kappa.\kappa_s\}$ when $\kappa$ is invariant curvature of the curve,  $s$ is invariant acrlength and $\kappa_s$ is derived of curvature by acrlength. Let's denote Cartan's signature of curve $C$ as $S(C)$.

Euclidean/Equi-affine transform is transform from $R^2$ to $R^2$ such $T(v) = A v + t$ when $v$ is each point of the curve, $t$ is constant and for Euclidean transform $A^TA=AA^T=Id$ and for Equi-affine transform $\det(A)=1$

Let's denote Curve $C$ after Euclidean transform as $\hat C$ and after Equi-affine transform as $\bar C$

I'm looking for any information if curve Cartan's signature is the same after Euclidean transform and after Equi-affine transform.

I mean $S(C)=S(\hat C)$ is it true?
and this one $S(C)=S(\bar C)$?

sorry if something not clear, I did my best.

It's kind of thoeretical part of this question:
[image]

**EDIT**

My results to original question:

1. Euclidean transform keep Cartan's signature
2. Equi-affine transform change Cartan's signature

but it based on numerical results of couple of examples.

the curve that I worked with is $[cos(t),sin(t)+0.2*sin(t)^2]$ when $t\in[0,2\pi)$ in sampled in 1000 points uniformly.

Original curve
[image]

Cartan's signature
[image]

Curve after Euclidean transform $
A = \begin{pmatrix}
cos(\theta) & sin(\theta) \\
-sin(\theta) & cos(\theta) 
\end{pmatrix};
b = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
-1 
\end{pmatrix}
$ when $\theta = \pi/4$
[image]

Cartan's signature after Euclidean transform
[image]

Curve after Equi-affine transform $
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0.5 & 1.5 
\end{pmatrix};
b = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
-1 
\end{pmatrix}$
[image]

Cartan's signature after Equi-affine transform

[image]

Comment: You say you did your best, but why don't you share some computations with us? Did you start by seeing what happens to $\kappa$ and to $s$ when you do the two types of transformations?

Comment: @TedShifrin my answer added

Comment: That probably should have gone into the question itself as an edit. But, yes, Euclidean transformations (isometries) preserve $\kappa$ and $s$. Equi-affine transformations preserve areas of parallelograms. Can you fit $\kappa_s$ into that framework somehow (think about the Frenet equations)?

Comment: @TedShifrin, Thank you.